# Navigate to Child Module Components Route from App Module Components

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

How Can i navigate to profile page after clicking login:
Also can anyone explain how child modules components are accessed from parent components.
I am sorry but I am putting my code as of below to get you understanding how am i working

This is how i generate my project:-

```
ng new angular
cd angular
ng g c components/login
ng g m nav -m=app.module
ng g c nav
ng g c nav/components/navrbar
ng g c nav/components/profile
ng g s services/auth
ng g i interfaces/auth
ng g g guards/auth
```

This is my Project Structure:-

```
Folder> components> Folder(login component)
Folder> guards
Folder> interfaces
Folder> nav> nav component + nav module + Folder(Components> Navbar and Profile)
Folder> Service
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { NavModule } from './nav/nav.module';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'nav', loadChildren: 'app/nav/nav.module#NavModule'},
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: LoginComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    ),
    // other imports here
    BrowserModule,
    NavModule,
    // import HttpClientModule after BrowserModule.
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

nav.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';


import { NavComponent } from './nav.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './components/profile/profile.component';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { AuthGuard } from '../guards/auth.guard';


const navRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '',
  component: NavComponent ,
  children: [
    {
        path: 'profile',
        component: ProfileComponent
    }
]
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(
      navRoutes // <-- debugging purposes only
    ),
    // other imports here
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [  AuthService, AuthGuard],
  declarations: [NavComponent, NavbarComponent, ProfileComponent]
})
export class NavModule { }
```

login.components.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router : Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    this.router.navigate(['/profile']);        
  }
  email : any;
  password : any;
  onSubmit(){
    let loginData = {
      email : this.email,
      password : this.password
    };
    this.authService.loginConfig(loginData)
    .subscribe((data:any) => {
        if(!data || data.status==200){
          console.log("response login data==>",data)
          this.authService.storeUserData(data.token, data);
          this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
        } else{
          alert(data.message)
        }
      });
    }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<app-login></app-login>
```

nav.component.html

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<!-- Routed views go here -->
```

As I am not sure how could I Do to reach from Login to Profile .

Answer (score 1):

The better practice would be to create the "RoutingModule" for each Module, so that you can split your routes and module/component/provider depenencies apart.

But let's do it on your code now.
In order to navigate to your profile component which is located in the NavModule, you have to define the route in AppModule in your case, which points against the NavModule.

So your routes in the AppModule should look like this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'profile', loadChildren: './nav/nav.module#NavModule'
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: LoginComponent }
];
```

We've defined that when the url will match "profile", it will check the routes in the NavModule. Therefore we have to define routes in the NavModule as well.
Since you have already defined the route for profile, we just have to do a slight change here. Instead of pointing the path to "profile", you have to point it to the root "". Because otherwise you will match it only when you access /profile/profile. So your routes in NavModule should look like this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '',
    component: ProfileComponent ,
    canActivate:[AuthGuard]}
];
```

Comment: Exactly answered my question in the shortest way, Thanks!